# Optimizing with BCE is not working, nothing will change

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import keras
from random import choice
import sys
devicet = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device = torch.device(devicet)
if devicet == 'cpu':
  print ('Using CPU')
else:
  print ('Using GPU')
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.step1 = nn.Linear(5, 25)
        self.step2 = nn.Linear(25, 50)
        self.step3 = nn.Linear(50, 100)
        self.step4 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.step5 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.step6 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
    def forward(self, x):
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step1(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step2(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step3(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step4(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step5(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      x = self.step6(x)
      x = F.relu(x)
      return (x)
net = Net()
x = torch.rand(10,5)
num = choice(range(10))
zero_tensor = torch.zeros(num, 1)
one_tensor = torch.ones(10-num, 1)
y = torch.cat((zero_tensor,one_tensor),0)
x.to(devicet)
y.to(devicet)
learning_rate = 1e-3
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_fn = torch.nn.BCELoss()
acc_list = []
for i in tqdm(range(1000),desc='Training'):
    y_pred = net(x)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    acc_list.append(abs(net(x).detach().numpy()[0]-y.detach().numpy()[0]))
    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in net.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad
    optimizer.zero_grad()
print ('\nFinished training in {} epochs.'.format(len(acc_list)))
plt.plot(range(len(acc_list)),acc_list)
plt.show()
for i in range(10):
  print (str(net(x).detach().numpy()[i][0])+', '+str(y.detach().numpy()[i][0]))
```

When I run this, it consistently just prints out the following:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4YD.png)

Why won't it do any training? It works if I use MSE loss (actually, it only works sometimes with MSE loss, sometimes it does the same thing as in the image) , it's only when I use BCE that it stops working entirely.

Comment: It's just the one

Comment: as far as I can tell x and y are completely unrelated. How exactly do you expect to predict `y` given no information related to `y`?

Comment: @jodag It should fit to random data for this small example anyway

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I guess that's true since `y` never changes. It seems a bit strange to be using all this heavy machinery to encode a constant.

Comment: @jodag makes sense to fit small random data for debugging the architecture/pipeline, also not the worst idea when learning PyTorch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final layer activation

You are outputting only positive values, those should be between `0` and `1` for starters, these line specifically:

```
x = F.relu(x)
return (x)
```

Use `torch.sigmoid` with `BCELoss` or even better, just output `x` and use [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) which uses logits directly

### Training

You are using `Adam` optimizer and doing SGD manually here:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for param in net.parameters():
        param -= learning_rate * param.grad
```

Essentially you are applying optimization step twice which is probably too much and might destroy the weights.

**`optimizer.step()` already does this, no need for both!**

### Accuracy

This part:

```
abs(net(x).detach().numpy()[0]-y.detach().numpy()[0])
```

I assume you want to calculate accuracy, it would go like this (also **do not push data through the network twice via `net(x)`, you already have `y_pred`!**):

```
# Assuming sigmoid activation
def accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
    # For logits use
    # predicted_labels = y_pred > 0.0
    predicted_labels = y_pred > 0.5
    return torch.mean((y_true == predicted_labels).float())
```

Comment: Implemented it, it works perfect, thanks so much! I'm fairly new to PyTorch, and this helped a lot!